# Controlling a display property in responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, displaytag

Good day, I have this question:

Say I have a div for a mobile displays:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="#"/>
</div>
```

And now for tablets I would like to destroy the "wrapper" div and safe the img.
CSS for tablet displays:

```
#wrapper {display: none:}
```

This will destroy the wrapper but the img too, is there anyway to safe the img using just CSS and not Jquery ?

Thanks
Renzo

I will try to show what is the real problem with the design of this site, is definitely more complicated than my simple question.

The design:

http://www.abejanegra.com/images/design_problem_a.jpg

What I need:

http://www.abejanegra.com/images/design_problem_b.jpg

I'm confused about this solution.

Comment: That won't be possible using CSS alone. Since you're setting the `display` property of `#wrapper` to `none`, all of the child elements inside it will be hidden as well.

Comment: however, you can make one tablet-wrapper (hide it for the rest of devices), and show image you want in it?

Comment: I edit my question posting two images

Comment: I don't know why you would need to hide and show a div. You don't have anything to go on but this is a responsive layout as per your image. It's mobile first. http://jsbin.com/ragodo/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on media queries. You can do amazing things.

Also, the world is a lot deeper than jquery. I love it, but check out asp.net and C#, or even php. Code behind is extremely powerful. You could do what you're trying to do very very easily.

Comment: No problem. Maybe a thumbs up?

Comment: Sorry, there you are now.